# Automatic resize content - one page website

Tags: jquery, browser, resize

I recently came across these website's: http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/ and http://www.tokiolab.it

If you look at the website's they are all one page, but the content scales as if it all are single pages.

I think it's nice how the content automatically adapts to the resolution of your browser (when resizing) even though it is an one page website.

Is this a new technique? Is it difficult to write such a plugin or do they exist already?

Hope someone can help me

Comment: there are some jquery plugins to do things like this, but its really to do with scroll animation.

Comment: i know how to create the animations, I am curious how the scaling of the site works.

If you look at the website's they are all one page, but the content scales as if it all single pages.

Comment: At risk of sounding pat, CSS has percent as a unit type which can be used to arrange things in terms of percent of containing element.

Comment: any directions for me to get to know more about this?

Comment: Why thumb down :( - I'm here to learn.. If i see something cool at the web i ask for directions to learn / achieve these functions.

Comment: thats just CSS, they probably made use of the `top,left,right, bottom` and worked with percentages,and not pixels,points, em etc...

Comment: Val - Thanks .. sounds obvious, so they tweak it with css & jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making websites adapt to a variety of screen sizes is, like Dominic shows, a whole book, not a quick fix.

It sounds like you're just looking to have multiple stacked sections, each section being the screen's height. Is that right?

That, alone, isn't too hard:

Set the width and height on the body and html elements to max out the page. I know, it's odd that you have to set the html element too, but that's life.

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

In your markup define your sections.

```
<section>...</section>
<section>...</section>
<section>...</section>
```

And resize your sections to fit on load and when the page is resized. Something like:

```
function draw() {
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();

    $("section").width(width).height(height);
}

$(document).resize(draw);
$(draw);
```

If you also what the scrolling to snap to the sections, define what's fixed and what scrolls with the page, entry and exit animations, etc... that becomes more involved. I don't know that there's a simple plugin that will do it for you. The closest might be impress.js (http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/).

Answer (score 0):

The principle you are looking at is responsive design, there is a ton off articles around about it.

A good book is http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

Article : http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Also if you want to retrofit some features you can just use media queries

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: This site is not responsive at all. It simply has a fancy method of scrolling the page.

Comment: I know responsive, but these websites doesn't seem to use mediaqueries

Comment: Responsive does not have to use media queries, just percentage units etc. I know the sites at the top are not responsive @RoryMcCrossan but the best approach is to use repsonsive design

Comment: Granted, but responsive design is about making the website fit to the medium it is being viewed on. The OP is about the scrolling effect the website he links to uses.

Answer (score 0):

Like Val said, more to do with scroll effects than page size.

Both those examples look like Scrollorama pages (http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/)

Another good one is http://www.nikebetterworld.com/product.

Comment: I know how the scroll events are done, i was just curious how the resizing works, if you look at these websites the content automaticly fits the browsers height / width although it is a single page website.